# How to generate an enum with associated values using swift macros?

Tags: swift, swift-macro

When trying to generate an enum with associated values, the generated enum is missing comma separating it's values.

This is the my expansion function (I'm using a PeermMacro)

```swift
public enum MyMacro: PeerMacro {

    public static func expansion(
        of _: AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf _: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in _: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        [
            DeclSyntax(
                EnumDeclSyntax(name: "MyEnum") {
                    EnumCaseDeclSyntax {
                        EnumCaseElementSyntax(
                            name: "myCase",
                            parameterClause: EnumCaseParameterClauseSyntax(
                                parameters: EnumCaseParameterListSyntax(
                                    [
                                        EnumCaseParameterSyntax(type: TypeSyntax("Int")),
                                        EnumCaseParameterSyntax(type: TypeSyntax("String"))
                                    ]
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        ]
    }
}
```

The code above generates the following code, which doesn't compile because there's a comma missing between the associated values:

```swift
enum MyEnum {
    case myCase(Int String)
}
```

How can I update my expansion code so that the generated code contains comma between my associated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same way that you passed a result builder closure to `EnumDeclSyntax` and `EnumCaseDeclSyntax`, you can do that to `EnumCaseParameterListSyntax` too.

```
EnumCaseParameterListSyntax {
    EnumCaseParameterSyntax(type: TypeSyntax("Int")),
    EnumCaseParameterSyntax(type: TypeSyntax("String"))
)
```

Many of the AST nodes conform to `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation`, so you can further simplify this to

```
EnumCaseParameterListSyntax {
    "Int"
    "String"
)
```

In fact, given a list of enum case parameters, you can generate the whole enum declaration using an interpolated string literal:

```
static func enumDeclWithParameters(_ list: [EnumCaseParameterSyntax]) -> DeclSyntax {
    let parameterList = EnumCaseParameterListSyntax {
        for elem in list {
            elem
        }
    }
    return """
    enum MyEnum {
        case myCase(\(parameterList)
    }
    """
}
```